# Layout Constraint errors while accessing Local html textbox or dropdown in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

Using Objective-C in XCode Version 11.2 (11B52) and macOS Catalina Beta 10.15.2 with iOS version 12.4.3.
Having different layout constraint errors while accessing Local html elements in Xcode.
Appreciate your help.

Tried these:

view.userInteractionEnabled = YES
view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO

```
   NSString *filePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"search" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:nil];
   NSLog(@"%@",filePath);
   self.webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
   self.webView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;  
   [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]]];
```

Expected: On selecting dropdown or search textbox in html while running it in Xcode on phone, I get all layout and constraint errors.
Actual: It has to get the selected item and go to the next screen to print the results.